# Switching between 2D and 3D mapview (pitchEnabled)

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, 2d, mapkit

I have an iOs map-application where the 3D view is utilized by default. Thus, the `MKMapCamera` is set in the beginning (the pitch value being `45`). However, I want to give users an option to disable the 3D-map in case they prefer the 2D-map. So in order to make the switch between views, I'll change the camera's pitch (`0` in 2D, `45` in 3D) and disable/enable changing it (`setPitchEnabled = NO/YES`).

For some reason I'm not able to anymore enable the 3D view after I've once disabled the pitch, i.e. after I've once set `[_mapView setPitchEnabled:NO]`, I cannot change it to `YES` anymore (After trying to change it back to `YES`, the `pitchEnabled` keeps its value as `NO` when its printed in `NSLog`). **Therefore I cannot get back from 2D to 3D. Do you have any idea what would be causing this?** It is very confusing, because I tried enabling and disabling the rotation (`[_mapView setRotationEnabled:NO]` or `YES`) in the same manner, and in that case it works perfectly between these two cases. But not with the pitch - after disabling the pitch I'm not able to enable it anymore. Below are the functions that set camera in the beginning (`setCamera`) and function that toggles between modes (`toggleViewMode`).

```
//Function that sets the 3D-view in the beginning

-(void)setCamera {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D userLocation;
    userLocation.latitude = self.locationManager.currentLatitude;
    userLocation.longitude = self.locationManager.currentLongitude;

    if(_cameraSet == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Camera is set already, return");
        return;
    }


    if ([_mapView respondsToSelector:@selector(camera)] && _show3Dmap) {

        _cameraSet = YES;
        [_mapView setShowsBuildings:NO];

        MKMapCamera *newCamera = [[_mapView camera] copy];
        [newCamera setPitch:45.0];
        [newCamera setHeading:0.0];
        [newCamera setAltitude:500.0];

        [_mapView setCamera:newCamera animated:NO];
    } 
}


//Toggle between 2D and 3D
-(void)toggleViewMode:(BOOL)birdView {

    if(birdView == YES) {
        _mapView.camera.pitch = 45;
        [_mapView setPitchEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        _mapView.camera.pitch = 0;
        [_mapView setPitchEnabled:NO];
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer elsewhere.
You have to set a camera also.

Here is a sample camera init :

```
MKMapCamera *newCamera = [[self.mapView camera] copy];
[newCamera setPitch:45.0];
[newCamera setHeading:90.0];
[newCamera setAltitude:500.0];
[self.mapView setCamera:newCamera animated:YES];
```

Comment: What are these magical values :45,90,500 (pitch,Heading,Altitude)?
Are they dependent?
And at what extent I can give value to pitch. What I observed I can see it around 56 max. 
Can you please explain a bit around this values?

Answer (score 0):

Please see Discussion here at apple document.

[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452277-camera#discussion][1]

You have to play with the pitch property to toggle between the 2D and 3D map view